# Add WYSIWYG to already existing textareas without losing PHP functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some existing forms with text areas made for editing. They first retrieve information from the database, the user can edit them and then update them in the database.

The problem is that in the database I have some text from MS Word and in the textareas I see Word formatting. I tried using TinyMCE Editor, but it replaces the existing textareas with custom code - losing classnames and other things that I refer to in my code and nothing works anymore.

Is there any minimal WYSIWYG editor that I could implement into my website without losing the already existing functionality?

Or are there any ways to change the Word formatting without using a plugin?

This is my example form:

```
<form id="myForm7" action="api/userInfo_1.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <textarea id="nazwa-artysty" type="textarea" name="Nazwa" class="nazwa"></textarea>

    Songs: <textarea type="text" name="Piosenki" class="piosenki"></textarea>

    <textarea type="input" id="" name="Id7" class="hidden-pic"  ></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="cms-button">Save</button> 
 </form>
```

The text to be edited is inserted into the textareas via PHP using the name of the textarea in $.POST. When using TinyMCE, the textarea doesn't exist anymore and therefore there's no text inserted into it.

Comment: Not sure how "the text is inserted via PHP" when you are using `$.post`. If you insert it in PHP, it should be done directly when you output the form itself. Then TinyMCE should use the contents of the `textarea` directly.

Comment: should be able to preserve original using options of editor, read the ap docs

Comment: Ok, I read them before but maybe I missed something, I'll look more carefully into them knowing that it's possible. Thank you!